# WSL does not work after Windows 10 Update

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-insider

I have joined the Windows 10 Insider Preview.  Today the system updated to version 2004 build 19555.1001, and now I cannot open WSL.

I'm seeing the following errors when running in CMD:

```bash
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19555.1001]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>bash
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>wsl
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>ubuntu
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: Please see this issue https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4860.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thank you, it really helps!

Comment: It really doesn't because I am running 19559.1000 and my WSL instances work without an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [WSL/issues/4860](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4860) (thanks @Biswapriyo)

This problem appears with 3 conditions:

1. System build 19555.1001 (original issue [WSL/issues/4860](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4860))
2. WSL2 ([comment1](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4860#issuecomment-580689950), [comment2](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4860#issuecomment-580841600))
3. `$Env:Path.length`(`%PATH%`) too long ([comment3](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4860#issuecomment-580938962))

Accordingly there are 3 solutions:

1. Roll back Win 10 update ([comment4](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4860#issuecomment-580938005))
2. Switch to WSL1 ([comment2](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4860#issuecomment-580841600), not recommend)
3. Reduce `$Env:Path.length`, for me 2k+ → 1058 works.

It seems clear that it will be solved in a future build, but there also seem to be different different answers about build 19559 -- See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4860#issuecomment-583085326) which says it not solved and @Ramhound's comment above that said his WSL works on that build without an issue.