# WSL2 - Cannot start Ubuntu distro

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to setup WSL2 to use Ubuntu on my host machine.
However I get the following error once I try to start the distro by executing `wsl -d Ubuntu-18.04`:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
respond after a period of time,or established connection failed because
connected host has failed to respond.
```

Starting it using the start menu will just open a blank terminal which closes after a timeout of ~3 seconds.

## Some host-specific info:

[wsl --list --verbose | output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHpFd.png) 
[Windows version info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XOY1.png)

I installed the Ubuntu version using the Windows Store (not using a tarball) and using the latest recommended Ubuntu LTS version (18.04). **WSL1** *works fine*.

I tried hard-rebooting to empty Windows' cache/memory and https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4371#issuecomment-521107556

Just wanted to know if I'm doing something stupidly wrong or if this is a bug on Windows' side.

Comment: Update to the current fast ring build.  This issue was fixed in that build.  As beta software you might encounter issues like this.

Comment: It is odd you have both a version 1 and version 2 instance.  Was that always the case?

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/1523754/726810

Comment: Did you set up the Hypervisor properly ? Make it so that the hypervisor starts up automatically on startup.